# Ruby on Rails App Testing with Rspec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, subdomain, rspec-rails

when i create a feature test for my application get the following error:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/example"
```

My application uses subdomains and sub-applications(engines/modules) within these subdomains. Now when i set for Capybara the app_host or default_host through an feature_subdomain_helper like

```
Capybara.app_host = "example.lvh.me" or
Capybara.default_host = "example.lvh.me"
```

and into my rails_helper.rb i add the following code line

```
  config.extend SubdomainHelpers, type: :feature
```

I get the same error. Now i think the configured subdomain are not considered by my feature test.

My Rspec Version is: 3.2
and Capybara Version is: 2.4.4

My sample feature test looks like:

```
require 'rails_helper'
feature 'Example Page' do

  scenario 'visit example page' do

    visit "/example"

    expect(page).to have_content 'Example'
  end
end
```

Have someone an idea what i do wrong?

Edit:
Mainapp routes:

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
  mount Example::Engine => '/', as: 'example'
end
```

Engine routes:

```
Example::Engine.routes.draw do

  scope '/example', nav_scope: 'example' do
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your routes.rb look like?

Comment: Add routes entries//Edited

Answer (score 0):

The names of Capybara.default_host and Capybara.app_host are slightly misleading since they both need to be set as URLs to function properly

```
Capybara.default_host = "http://example.lvh.me"
```

If that doesn't fix your issue check `rake routes` and make sure the action you think is mounted at '/example' really is.

Comment: The route exists and is mounted at '/example'. And when the default_host and app_host or only on is setted. Thats the reason why i didn't understand the problem.

Comment: @puQ did you fix your app_host and default_host settings to be URLs rather than just hostnames as I mentioned in my answer? Did that make a difference?

Comment: Yes i have fix my app_host/default_host settings to be URLs. And the result is the same error

Comment: @puQ If the route definitely exists at the correct place and your capybara settings are correct then I think the only option left is your code not correctly extracting the subdomain in your Subdomain constraint

Comment: But in production everything works fine with the subdomain constraint.. only the test case is "buggy"

Comment: Okay fixed the problem.. it was my subdomain setting.. just forgot for the test part to seeding mit test database correctly >.<

thank you tom!