# Capybara doesn't find my route in engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I started a new Rails 5 applications for myself to see how I can modularise an application with engines and simple test purposes. 
I decided to use Rspec and Capybara for integration tests.

I have a very basic feature rspec:

okinsmen/components/okm_backend/spec/features/humen_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "Humen process" do
  scenario "go to index page" do
    visit '/humen'
    expect(page).to have_content("List of humen")
  end
end
```

That's my route:

okinsmen/components/okm_backend/config/routes.rb

```
    OkmBackend::Engine.routes.draw do
      root 'dashboards#index'
      resource :dashboards, only: [:index]
      resources :humen
    end
```

And the result of the command *rails app:routes* in the terminal:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern  Controller#Action
okm_backend      /okm_backend OkmBackend::Engine

Routes for OkmBackend::Engine:
      root GET    /                         okm_backend/dashboards#index
     humen GET    /humen(.:format)          okm_backend/humen#index
           POST   /humen(.:format)          okm_backend/humen#create  new_human GET    /humen/new(.:format)      okm_backend/humen#new edit_human GET    /humen/:id/edit(.:format) okm_backend/humen#edit
     human GET    /humen/:id(.:format)      okm_backend/humen#show
           PATCH  /humen/:id(.:format)      okm_backend/humen#update
           PUT    /humen/:id(.:format)      okm_backend/humen#update
           DELETE /humen/:id(.:format)      okm_backend/humen#destroy
```

All looks good, but I get always this error:

```
1) Humen process go to index page
     Failure/Error: visit '/humen'

     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/humen"
```

If I replace visit "/humen" by humen_path, I get this error:

```
  1) Humen process go to index page
     Failure/Error: visit humen_path

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `humen_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::HumenProcess:0x00000006843ea0>
```

To solve this last issue, I have to add this line in my rails_helper.spec:

```
config.include OkmBackend::Engine.routes.url_helpers
```

Now the test pass.

But I can't get the test working with a string URL.

The application can be looked at https://github.com/patdec/okinsmen/tree/engines

It's very basic.
Thanks if you can help me.

**Update:**

If I write my spec like this (as anwered by Tom Walpole):

```
scenario "go to index page" do
    visit '/okm_backend/humen'
    expect(page).to have_content("Humen list")
  end
```

it works

But this not:

```
scenario "display new page" do
    click_on '/okm_backend/humen/new'
    expect(page).to have_content("New human")
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your spec/dummy/config/routes.rb you're mounting the engine at /okm_backend for test purposes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount OkmBackend::Engine => "/okm_backend"
end
```

That means to call `visit` with a string would need to be

```
visit '/okm_backend/humen'
```

Comment: In this case It works. But I mounted the engine OkmBackend at '/'. I use a subdomain to access it. I don't have to prefix my url with /okm_backend. No ?

Comment: May be this post would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922936/ruby-on-rails-app-testing-with-rspec-and-capybara

Comment: @padrec You may have mounted it at / in your main app, but for the tests on your engine you've mounted it at /okm_backend as shown in the code I posted

Comment: @patdec Great - don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) if it helped you so the question gets marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use `engine_name.some_path`, which in your case is:

```rb
okm_backend.humen_path
# returns /okm_backend/humen
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing `app.humen_path` in your rails console? You have to use that string as the URL.

Comment: I got this error: NoMethodError: undefined method `humen_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x000000050f1298>

Comment: If I type app.okm_backend.humen_path, I get '/humen'

Comment: You are doing it wrong @patdec `app.okm_backend.humen_path` should be just `okm_backend.humen_path`. I added an answer below if anyone needs it.